# nodejs doesnt serve anything after deserializeuser is completed successfully

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

My stack is Nodejs, Passportjs, Mysql and Angularjs. When I am authenticating the user using passport facebook strategy, after a session is created, nodejs server just doesnt return anything at all, I just see `[object Object]` in the browser. On nodejs console, I notice that request for query for getting user details by `deserializeUser` function was run but after that it just returns from there. Can someone please explain what is happening here.
If the user is not authenticated, i.e. no session is created, then I can access all my webpages without any issues. Following is my `deserializeUser` function

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id).then(function(user) {
        var err = {};
        var tmpUser = {id: user.id, id_facebook: user.id_facebook, name: user.name, email: user.email};
        done(err,tmpUser);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try setting `err` to `null` instead of `{}`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Damn had to spend so much time just due to this.

Comment: You are welcome. It's because empty object is different from `null`. It makes the `done` callback thinks that you are throwing an error.